# Using past simple or past perfect after *since*?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple

This is an exercise from my English book:

> You three boys look very guilty! What *did you do* / *have you done* / *have you been doing* since I *left* / *have left*?

I chose *have you been doing* and *have left*. But the correct answer for the second option is *left*. Why is that? I thought past perfect was used after *since*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. What have you been doing since I left?
> 2. What did you do after I left?
> 3. What have you done since I left?

are all correct and natural, in my opinion. "had left" would seem awkward and unnatural to me in any of the three examples above. In fact i can't think of a natural sentence using "since I had left" to indicate a point in time.

> Since i had left, i didn't hear the speech.

is valid, but in that case "since" means "because" and does not specify a point in time.

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary's article on "*since*"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/since)

> When since introduces an action or event at a point of time in the past, we can use the past simple or present perfect after since and the present perfect in the main clause.

...

> When since introduces a state in the past that is still continuing in the present, we use a present perfect form of the verb after since and a present perfect form of the verb in the main clause:
>
> > "Since I’ve been back at work, I’ve been feeling great."

(The Cambridge article includes additional examples, which I did not copy here.)